# Configure NGINX for multiple odoo instances

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, odoo

i have installed two odoo instances on my VPS, now i'm trying to configure nginx to use both domains with their ports, i am a beginner in nginx, i tried searching in the web but nothing is clear enough, i followed a guide on how to install odoo but it only shows  nginx configuration for a single domain.

this is the config i'm currently using :

```
upstream odooserver {
     server 127.0.0.1:8050;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name www.domain.com;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/odooe_error.log;

     proxy_read_timeout 720s;
     proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
     proxy_send_timeout 720s;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

     location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://odooserver;
     }

     location ~* /web/static/ {
         proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
         proxy_buffering on;
         expires 864000;
         proxy_pass http://odooserver;
     }

     gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
     gzip on;
 }
```

Comment: There are many many... MANY explanations about setting such configuration file style under Nginx. With respect, i am wondering if you took time and minimal efforts into researching/reading/understanding/experimenting/implementing/testing/enjoying before posting on here. I value your participation but i must say i value the overall community and epurated content. There is almost no end to asking the same question for the MANY (again haha) possible, very specific use cases. Just a HINT... add another upstream, copy the server block, change proxy_pass to match and other stuff..

Comment: i did 2 days of continuous browsing, and looking through different guides, yes i didn't take the full time to read the entire nginx documentation but that would take freaking ages, and considering that my goal isn't to learn or play around, i was told to make this website asap.
anyway i did many experiments, including what you mentioned, but i'm still stuck,i tried changing dns settings but it only got worse, btw what do you mean by "change proxy_pass to match and other stuff"?

Comment: @masterofconsfu Usually there are two ways to do what you are asking for in general. The first way is to use subdomains (e.g. `app1.domain.com`, `app2.domain.com`) and several server blocks with different server names (`server_name app1.domain.com`, `server_name app2.domain.com`, etc.) The second way is to use URI prefixes (e.g. `domain.com/app1/`, `domain.com/app2/`). However a web app itself should support this, and a (very) quick googling about odoo shows nothing but [this](https://www.odoo.com/ru_RU/forum/pomoshch-1/openerp-7-web-non-root-url-prefix-33279) question with no answers.

Comment: For both of the ways you will need two different odoo instances listening different ports (or WSGI sockets), each one using its own postgress database, and two different upstreams (e.g. `upstream odoosrv1 { ... }` and `upstream odoosrv2 { ... }`) defined in your nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

it's working now after editing the config file like the others suggested, and it turned out that there was something wrong with the DNS settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).